# how to search a data in particular fields(ms access database) in vb6.0 using data1 control

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, ms-access, vb6

how to search a data in particular fields(ms access database) in vb6.0 using data1 control.
I create a project in vb 6.0 using ms access data base and data control. I want to find a particular name from the data base table field.
My code is....

```
If Data1.Recordset.Fields("C_Number") = Text15.Text Then 
MsgBox "ok"
Else 
MsgBox "not" End If
```

But it is find first record only, how cant I find the particular data of all data in the field. Please help me.

Comment: Perhaps you need to loop through all records in the recordset, moving to the next record by calling the recordset MoveNext method, until you've either found the desired record or you've reached the end of the records (the EOF property is True)?  See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675841(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Thank you Sir for replying.                                                                        Can you tell me how to use the loop and what loop use in this position? Please help me sir. Every example base on ADO or Adodc. But I used data control. So, Please help me sir.

Comment: Lots of examples and tutorials exist on the web.  Here's one that goes through the different types of loops available in vb6: http://www.freetutes.com/learn-vb6/lesson4.html.  Try it!

Comment: Private Sub Command7_Click() 
For i = 1 To toda* 
If Data1.Recordset.Fields("C_Number"**) = Text15.Text(i) Then
MsgBox "ok" 
else
MsgBox "not ok" 
End If 
Next i 
End Sub 
But it is not work, not find any record even first record. no massage showing
* total number of record store in the integer variable "toda"
** the table field name
*** search textbox

 please help me...

Answer (score 0):

Try this Code:

```
Private Sub Command7_Click()
 MsgBox toda ' Check If you get Value into this.
  For i = 1 To toda
   If Data1.Recordset.Fields("C_Number") = Text15.Text then
       MsgBox "OK"
   Else
       MsgBox "Not OK"
   End If
   Data1.Recordset.MoveNext
  Next i   
End Sub
```

Check if you are getting any data into the toda variable.